# TFS: Comparator in datetime field of workitem (2015)

Tags: tfs

Is there any way to deny the entry of past dates being selected in a date time field for a workitem?

As far as I can tell comparators aren't allowed, so a huge list of "prohibitedvalues" would be the only way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot achieve that as no such a built-in feature or a `field rule` applying for this.

For now we can only use the existing rules to restrict the files. Please see [Add a rule to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=vsts) for details.

Yeah, `PROHIBITEDVALUES` rule can deny the values added to the list. But it's a rough way...

You can submit a UserVoice at https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services to suggest the feature.